# PHP- Finding the Sum of values for each ID in an Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have 2 Arrays. The First Array is a 1D Array which contains User ID's.

Something like this Array `( [0] => 1042800 [2] => 1184921 [4] => 724911 [66] => 1271106 )`

I have a second Array which is an Associative Array, which contains Information for each User ID. It is something like this

```
Harvest_DayEntry::__set_state(array('user-id'=>1042800 'hours'=>2 ,Harvest_DayEntry::__set_state(array('user-id'=>1042800 'hours'=>4 ))
```

That was actually a part of the array. Now I am Interested in calculating the total hours for each User ID.

This is what I have tried.

```
//Add all the Hours for a Given User ID
//$output is the Array of User ID's
$resultGetEntries=$api->getProjectEntries($project_id,$range); 
$dayEntries= $resultGetEntries->data;  

$i=0;
$sum=$sum[20];
$sum= array_fill(0, 20, 0);

foreach ($dayEntries as $key => $value) {
    if($output[i] == $value->get("user-id")) {
        $sum[$i] = $sum[$i] + $value->get("hours");
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Eventually I want to get something like this

```
   User ID    Hours
   1042800       15      
   1184921       18
   724911        10 
   1271106        8
```

I am not too sure how to go about it. I can't seem to figure out how do I loop over an Associative array and calculate the sum for each user ID at the same time. I just need to know the proper logic to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `$resultGetEntries` is your user ids array and `$dayEntries` is the `Harvest_DayEntry`s array.

The simplest way to combine both is iterarting over both in a double loop:

```
$resultGetEntries = $api->getProjectEntries($project_id,$range); 
$dayEntries = $resultGetEntries->data;  

$sums = array();
foreach ($resultGetEntries as $i => $userId) {
    $sums[$userId] = 0;
    foreach ($dayEntries as $j => $dayEntry) {
        if ($dayEntry->get("user-id") == $userId) {
            $sums[$userId] += $dayEntry->get("hours");
        }
    }
}
print_r($sums);
```